# ie8 if-ie block doesn't work

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am testing one of my web pages for compatibility in different browsers.

I had some issues with ie8 and so i added well known `[if IE]` block to the code. This is the code I added.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ie-issue{
            top:0;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

But it doesn't rendering in my ie8 and cannot think of a way to get it work. Please help me on getting this done.

Comment: are you applying the `.ie-issue` class?

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the code you've shown. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: What part isn't working, the CC or the CSS? Please test by adding in some visible content, or taking the style block out of the CC. I'm guessing your CSS just isn't doing anything. `<style>` elements by themselves do not "render" anything. As far as the CSS goes, `top:0;` does nothing unless a `position` is set.

Comment: Is the conditional comment **before** or **after** any other definition of `.ie-issue`? Are you applying the `ie-issue` class to any html elements?

Comment: @Madmartigan ya i'm applying that style to a div element which previously had `top:100px`. anyhow i tried with visible element and yet the output is same. at least ie8's developer tool should show this style block ,doesn't it?

Comment: @thirtydot do you mind telling me any other possible ways of failing this. and i cannot see this style block inside the developer tool in ie8.

Answer (score 0):

Try `!important`. I would also specify `position:absolute` in you [if IE]. Finally, remember, negative numbers work as well `(top:-100px;)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the conditional to work properly, this is a good work around: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Answer (score -1):

Try `margin-top` instead of `top`.